# Black screen appears when open XIB file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xib

After merging my project with another branch, my ViewControllers show black screen when i call them. When i change my root from storyboard to custom ViewController with .xib file the black screen appeared. File owners on xib files, are set to their related ViewControllers. All IBOutlets are okay.

I tried to clean project, build project, even reboot my mac device, but still no results

Comment: Which iOS version are you using?

Comment: IOS Version on Simulator is 12.*